# What does one actually study when getting a Ph.D. in Liberal Studies from Georgetown University? Does one perhaps study liberals or study liberally?

Tags: terminology, political-science

After 06:33 in CNN's January 22, 2023 [Brown presses GOP House Intelligence chair on Trump documents](https://youtu.be/8t-FTAFcwBk?t=393) CNN's Pamela Brown says to US Representative [Mike Turner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Turner) (R-OH):

> Okay, thank you so much Congressman Mike Turner for that spirited discussion, this is why I like having you on, you put it all out there and (we can) still have a civil conversation. I appreciate your time.
>
> And also I want to mention to everyone, congratulations to you, you just received your doctorate from Georgetown in Liberal Studies. So congratulations.

[Georgetown University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgetown_University) is a highly regarded private institution were folks go to teach and to study a variety of topics including politics and law.

I was wondering why  a traditional conservative politician with 20 years as a Republican member of the US house of representatives (and now chairman of the House Intelligence Committee) either *study liberals or liberalism* or *study how to be liberal* or even *study liberally*

I decided that there must be more to this, and that I did not understand what "Liberal Studies" actual means. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What does one actually study when getting a Ph.D. in Liberal Studies from Georgetown University? Does one perhaps study liberals or study liberally?

Comment: It's very easy to find [what the program is about](https://scs.georgetown.edu/programs/43/doctor-of-liberal-studies/) on Google. Did you intend to ask *why* a Republican Senator might want to get that degree?

Comment: @JonathanReez my question post does explain that I am curious about that, but Politics SE questions about what's going on in the head of an individual quickly get closed, so I'm going to be cautious and start with a basic understanding of the program. And as always, one of the main goal of an SE question is to facilitate good answers. Let's see how answers evolve here, and if it turns out there's an on-topic question about "why a Republican Senator might want to get that degree" I'll see if I can write it up. *Thanks!*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_arts_education?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @Obie2.0 Liberal Studies = Liberal Arts? I've heard of a Bachelors in Liberal Arts, *but one can really get a Ph.D. in Liberal Arts at Georgetown University?*

Comment: They're using "liberal" in basically the same way.

Comment: If he congratulated the congressman on his daughter winning a volleyball tournament, would you ask a volleyball question here in Politics? Your Q is 100% about education. But if you ask over there, get rid of the snarky 2nd sentence in the title.

Comment: @OwenReynolds *Please! Self-deprecating levity;* I'm not the snarky type. Politics is not only about mud-slinging with one hand while (hopefully) legislating with the other, it's also an academic field of study, and academic questions about the study of politics are on topic here. Dry, academic questions may not be as fun for some to answer, but they do have a home here. Slightly related: [How to ask beginner-level questions on political theory or science?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4598/16047) I'm still getting my sea legs for this genre.

Comment: TLDR: it has nothing to do with colloquial "liberal" politics.

Comment: In English, **Liberal**, as a (umbrella) term for some types of secondary education, has no relationship whatsoever to any use of the term in political meanings.  I mean to some extent, it sounds so, ugh, *elitist* to have a PhD but...

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liberal%20arts  :  : college or university studies (such as language, philosophy, literature, abstract science) intended to provide chiefly general knowledge and to develop general intellectual capacities (such as reason and judgment) as opposed to professional or vocational skills

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica yes, that doesn't sound like something one gets a Ph.D. from Georgetown in.

Answer (score 2):

PhD programs are usually very broad, while individual study within a PhD program is very narrow. If you want to know what someone studied for their PhD, look for their thesis: these are typically published and available to the public at least through a library.

You could also just go to their [website](https://scs.georgetown.edu/programs/43/doctor-of-liberal-studies/) and read:

> Georgetown’s Doctor of Liberal Studies positions you at the intersection of multiple disciplines. You will explore philosophical, cultural, political, international, and current social concepts in a global context to develop a broader perspective of the complexities facing the modern world. Distinct from traditional Ph.D. programs, our interdisciplinary approach brings together different perspectives and fields of knowledge while addressing pressing issues.

You can at least see an abstract of his "Urban Fail" thesis here:

https://repository.library.georgetown.edu/handle/10822/1064648

It seems his thesis relates to the effects of government policies on urban areas.

> This thesis contends that federal urban policies have exacerbated the pressure of outmigration of urban populations and capital and contributed to a condition of urban core decline and decay. Central to this thesis is the contention that federal urban economic development policy is historically anchored upon a narrative of poverty intervention.

Comment: I understand that one can ask google or go to the appropriate Georgetown site, but I'm still confused about the name of the program itself. So can one conclude that Liberal Studies are not related to the study of [Liberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism)? If so, what is it that's actually so liberal about Liberal Studies?

Comment: @uhoh Why not check a dictionary and see which definition aligns best with their description? Perhaps multiple definitions will work.

Comment: Answers are of use to future readers as well; instead of each reader (at least fo those as unsophisticated as I am) reaching for their dictionary separately, perhaps a sentence or two here would add value to the site?

Comment: You're being a bit handwavy of his thesis. It's actually quite... [US] conservative [=right-wing]... in its thrust: "This thesis contends that federal urban policies have exacerbated the pressure of outmigration of urban populations and capital and contributed to a condition of urban core decline and decay. Central to this thesis is the contention that federal urban economic development policy is historically anchored upon a narrative of poverty intervention."

Comment: @Fizz I intentionally didn't want my answer to become a debate or discussion focus around the contents of this guy's thesis. It's the area of study, not the specific hypothesis, that makes a given thesis topic relevant to a particular graduate program.

Comment: That's reasonable, but since the Q was predicated on "liberal" [wordplay], this guy's thesis shows that one can occasionally see quite [US] conservative topics/thesis in such contexts/studies.

Comment: @Fizz I feel like that's just as likely to mislead someone into thinking that "liberal" here means "studying liberals and how they suck", so it isn't very helpful.